# json library that allows shared memory in c

Tags: c, json, shared-memory

I am trying to share a json object between multiple processes. The code is written in C. Currently I am using json-c, which works quite well. Is there a way to force the library to allocate into shared memory? If not, what c library will allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: consider your json just an array of bytes. sharing a trunk of bytes in C is just like eating cake

Answer (score 0):

Your question is OS specific. I guess it is on Linux.

I dont see an easy way (in particular for a varying JSON), since shared memory has some *fixed* size, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html). Or at least build the JSON string, then allocate the shared memory (of big enough size) for it and copy the JSON string.

Did you consider using a RAM filesystem, e.g. a *tmpfs* filesystem? That should be fast.

#### NB

Customizing the memory allocator of the JSON library (like [jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/apiref.html#custom-memory-allocation) does - source code is on [github](https://github.com/akheron/jansson)) is not enough, because different processes usually share memory at different addresses.

Comment: Basically all that is required is to be able to specify how memory is allocated and freed. Does anyone know of a json library that allows that.

Comment: @Mobius That depends. Shared memory segments is often mapped at different locations in different processes. That means you can't store objects that contains pointers in a shared memory segment, as those pointers are only valid within the process that created them.